# Database Migration with Timestamp in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am using Grails 2.2.4 and a mysql database, as well as the [database-migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).

For a given Class that is persistent in the database:

```
class User {
   String name
}
```

Then I added:

```
Date lastUpdated
```

and did:

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff 2013-09-09-lastUpdated.groovy -add
grails dbm-update
```

But when I look inside my database I can see 0000-00-00 00:00:00

How do I get a valid date e.g., new Date() as the default value?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set autoTimestamp (it could be false by default) :

```
static mapping = {
   autoTimestamp true
   ...
}
```

Or just use beforeUpdate :

```
def beforeUpdate() {
   lastUpdated = new Date()
}
```

Comment: This is not working the lastUpdated is still 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in all existing rows.

Comment: Try `def beforeInsert()` if you need to fill lastUpdated field when you create new `User`.

Comment: Do you have another idea?

Comment: Create test class with the same fields and create your own migration script for it (without dbm-gorm-diff). Check if approaches work. Another solution - create trigger in your DB to update lastUpdate field every tiem when data insert or update, but it's much complicated thing to do.